# Change the radius of Bing Heat Map circles on change of zoom

Tags: javascript, bing-maps, heatmap

I am working with Bing Maps and a heat map. I am successfully displaying the heat map. My problem is two-fold:

1. If the user double clicks on the map it zooms in, but the radius of my heat map circles doesn't change. Is there a way to change that?
2. If the user selects the + or - on the control to zoom in or out, is there a way to capture that event and then do what I asked in #1--change the radius of the radius of the heat map circles?v

Here is my GetMap() function that draws the map initially and any other relevant code:

```
var map;
var heatmapLayer;

function GetMap(myData) {
  /** If this is the first time the myData will be null so get all data **/

  if(myData == null){
    var myData = [];
    myData = myData.concat(HighRisk);
    myData = myData.concat(Ombuds);
  }
  map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("divMap"),
       { credentials: 'BING_MAPS_KEY',
         center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(36,-40),
         mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road,
         labelOverlay: Microsoft.Maps.LabelOverlay.visible,
         zoom: 1
        });

  // Register and load the Client Side HeatMap Module
  Microsoft.Maps.registerModule("HeatMapModule", "js/heatmap.js");
  Microsoft.Maps.loadModule("HeatMapModule", { callback: function() {
  Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'click', displayEventInfo);
    // Once the module is loaded, create a customised heatmap
    // by passing in various options as third parameter
    var myRadius = 400000;  


    heatmapLayer = new HeatMapLayer(
      map,
      myData,
      { intensity: 0.50, // "heat" at centre of each point
        radius: myRadius, // radius of affected area
        unit: "meters", // unit in which radius is measured
        showMapTypeSelector: false,
        colourgradient: {
          0.0: 'green',
          0.5: 'blue',
          0.75: 'orange',
          1.0: 'red'
        }
      });
  }});
  Microsoft.Maps.Location.prototype.multiplier = 50;

}

function displayEventInfo(e) {
      if (e.targetType == "map") {
          var point = new Microsoft.Maps.Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
          var loc = e.target.tryPixelToLocation(point);
          var options = map.getOptions();
          alert(map.getTargetZoom());

      }
  }
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this. The heat maps refreshes when double clicked or the zoom buttons are used. The radius of the circles are scaled based on the zoom level. In your case the circles will stay 400km in size. Side note, showMapTypeSelector is not an option of the heatmap, that's a map option.

Comment: But that's exactly my problem. When I zoom in the circles stay the same size so that when you try to zoom into a city to see the circles they are gigantic (400km) so how do I make them resize?

Comment: Here is a screen capture video of what the circles look like: http://screencast.com/t/BvaIYrcyVdFX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the unit option to 'pixels'. This will keep the size of the circles to a specified number of pixels. You will need to make the radius much smaller, like 40.